# Changing the VAR position on a output.write in python

Tags: python

Sorry the noob question, but I'm trying to do the following.

I'm trying to generate a txt file following this simple structure:

```
 with open("output_file.txt", "a") as output:
        output.write("1#"+str(AX)+"#"+str(FAT)+"#"+str(date)+"#"+str(TOTAL)+"#")
        output.write("\n")
```

This is working, but I'm trying to do a more advanced thing. I want to write the output depending on a template I want to create. So let's say I create a txt file that I will use as a template, and in the first line I will have this:

1#(TOTAL)#(AX)#(DATE)#(TOTAL)#1#(FAT)#0#

The question is, how can I change the output.write to follow the same order I insert in the template file? In this example, the output.write should be **output.write("1#"+str(TOTAL)+"#"+str(AX)+"#"+str(DATE)+"#"+str(TOTAL)+"1"+str(FAT)+"#0#"**

But I need this to be automatic, to change the output.write when I change the template.

I hope to have been clear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [string.Template](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Template). E.g.

```
from string import Template

template = Template('1#$TOTAL#$AX#$DATE#$TOTAL#1#$FAT#0#')

with open("output_file.txt", "a") as output:
    output.write(template.substitute(AX=str(AX), FAT=str(FAT), DATE=str(DATE), TOTAL=str(TOTAL)))
    output.write("\n")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!

Exactly what I need!